# using FreeMarker with EXPOSE_PROPERTIES_ONLY

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I'm learning about the FreeMarker templating engine, and noticed there's an [`EXPOSE_PROPERTIES_ONLY` feature](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_50) for exposing only getter methods to templates.

If that situation covers 99.9% of my object model, but I want to also expose one convenience method like `convertFeetToMeters(double feet)`, is there a way to denote that this method is OK to expose to FreeMarker, even though it's not a getter?

Answer (score 3):

I think the easies way of doing that would be not using the exposure level setting, but the `MethodAppearanceFineTuner` setting. There you can decide one by one which method to expose and how.

However, for helper methods like that you have shown as example, which addresses a presentation concern, I would not pollute my data-model. You can introduce such helper methods as `TemplateMethodModelEx`-es or as `#function`-s instead.